# Input xlsx or csv file in Kettle from microsoft sharepoint that needs login

Tags: kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pdi, data-integration

I want to input xlsx files or csv files from a microsoft sharepoint site that i need to login.

I have account on the sharepoint but Kettle Microsoft excel input step does not have options for login. The result is that the transformation gives an error that it cannot access the file.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

There is no such option to enter credential if you are reading files from share point .

But you have an option to download files using HTTP Client Steps in Pentaho,so first download them to any local unix/windows path, later you can process them using CSV file input/Excel Input option.

REST Client step is also available to read API's Data. Please work around.